# How does * to access pointers of variables or arrays work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a lot of confusion regarding arrays and pointer in C; to demonstrate it, here are my interpretations of some bits of code.

```
int main(void){
 int x[10]; //allocates memory for the array x with dimension 10 in the main function
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  x[i] = i; //for each index of x write the corresponding i number
 }
 readArray(x, 10); //calls the function readArray(), with 2 arguments, 
                   //the array x and its size, the constant 10
}
```

Now the confusing part is in the function readArray(), which should be defined before the main function.

```
int readArray(int *y, int size){ //creates the function readArray() with
                              //a pointer y to the array x (with the address of the 
                              //first element of x and its size
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  //here is the problem, I want to change the values
  //of the array x, but y is a pointer to x, therefore, to me, it should be as
  *y[i] = i; //an * is used to access the array x and change its value
  //the correct code, however is
   y[i] = i // this is supposed to also change the value of x,
            // but I thought to change the value we needed to use * as 
            // y is a pointer to x, therefore changing the values of x (because y is local to readArray())
 }
}
```

I know * is used for pointers, but the array is also a pointer, so why isn't it used?
Please correct what I wrote in the comments and explain when and where * should be used to change the value of a value pointed by another.

Comment: I don't quite get you're question, to be honest, but I guess you're thinking of `y[i] == *(y+i)`…

Comment: `int readArray(*y, dimension)` is that suppose dto be a function declaration? because it's completely missing per-argument type specifications. And you should learn sooner rather than later, *"but the array is also a pointer"* is flat-wrong. Arrays are not pointers. When used in an expression context their *value* representation is converted to a *temporary* pointer to first element. Pointers are *not* arrays; arrays are *not* pointers.

Comment: array will decay into pointer,  so `y[i]` statement will become `*(y+1)`

Comment: I’ll let somebody else answer but note that your first code comment is incorrect: the *size* of the array is 10, not its dimension. In fact, the *dimension* is 1.

Comment: when you call the function `readArray(x, 10)` the array `x` is converted to a pointer to its first element (some people say it "decays") so your comment is misleading. `readArray(x, 10); /* 2 arguments: a pointer and a length */`

Comment: C does not pass the array to a function. It always passes the address of the first element to the function. Inside the function, C allows a pointer to be treated as an array and so you can write `y[i]= i;`

Comment: for more detailed understanding of C, read [this](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)

Comment: `*y[i] = i;` is an error, you should get an error message (adjust compiler settings if you do not)

Comment: "y is a pointer to x" -- actually `y` is a pointer to `x[0]`. Recall that you initialized y as `x`, not `&x` .

Comment: @M.M I guess I got confused, because if you want to change a variable by its pointer you do *y (where y is a pointer to a variable) but it doesn't work in arrays. Is that right?

Comment: @DuarteArribas `*y` means the same as `y[0]`. The `[]` operator dereferences with offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readArray(x, 10); //calls the function readArray(), with 2 arguments, 
                   //the array x and its size, the constant 10
```

This does not actually pass the array `x`. When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument. So this passes a pointer to `x[0]`, not `x`.

```
int readArray(int *y, int size){ //creates the function   readArray() with
                              //a pointer y to the array x (with the address of the 
                              //first element of x and its size
```

The second part of the comment is correct, `y` receives the address of the first element of `x`. You should avoid thinking of it as the first part, a pointer to the array. A parameter `int *y` is a pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to an array. Even though an array and its first element may have the same value for their addresses (since they start in the same place), pointers to them have different types and behave differently.

```
*y[i] = i; //an * is used to access the array x and change its value
```

The subscript operator, `[ ]`, has higher precedence than `*`. So `*y[i]` is equivalent to `*(y[i])`. In `y[i]`, the index `i` is used to identify the element that is `i` elements beyond where `y` points. Then `y[i]` designates that element. By definition, `y[i]` is equivalent to `(*(y+i))`—the C implementation takes the pointer `y`, adds `i` to it, and then applies `*` to refer to the element at the resulting address.

When you then apply `*` to `y[i]`, you are attempting to apply `*` to an `int`, because `y[i]` is the `int` at the calculated location. So that yields an error message.

```
   y[i] = i // this is supposed to also change the value of x,
            // but I thought to change the value we needed to use * as 
            // y is a pointer to x, therefore changing the values of x (because y is local to readArray())
```

The subscript operator, `[ ]` has a built-in `*` operator. So `y[i]` is `*(y+i)`.

When you use the subscript operator with an array, as in `x[i]`, the array `x` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `x[i]` is actually `(&x[0])[i]`. And, by definition of the subscript operator, that is actually `*(&x[0] + i)`. So, when you use `x[i]`, the C implementation takes the address of the first element of `x`, adds `i` to it (counting in units of elements, not bytes), and then refers to that address.

Because of this automatic conversion of arrays to pointers and the definition of the subscript operator, you can use both `x[i]` (where `x` is an array) and `y[i]` (where `y` is a pointer) to refer to the element number `i`.

Answer (score -1):

The function readArray get a variable of type int* (y).
When you do y[i] you « cancel » the * and then you can change the value in y[i]. Actually y[i] is like *(y+i).
When you do *y[i] you are trying to use * on the element in y[i] and then the program makes you a bug.
Tell me if you understood :)

Ps: write readArray(int* y, int size) —>like this you can define a function (with the type of every variable)